# AWS S3 bucket "404 Not Found"

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

At the moment I'm hosting a bundled `Angular-2` App in an `AWS S3 bucket`, so it only contains `.html` and `.js` files.

The absolute path `http://example.com/` does work but if I switch to any links, such as `http://example.com/testsite` it returns `404 error` as below:

```sh
404 Not Found
Code: NoSuchKey
Message: The specified key does not exist.
Key: voucher
RequestId: 7A08F32C18D3C6D3
HostId: 6jTd5D5QDU+AP4vo+uRcHHVT5WeRAKjoPeqVb39xoKZZSvWWz/9TsNp41TbuKXmtpYbLZJiyqwE=
```

I already tried another bucket policy and I set every file to public, but it won't work for me.
Anyone has a solution? Please help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your bucket policy Resource property needs to contain, note the /*:

```
"Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"]
```

You also need to set the error document to be your index.html

Comment: Hoy do you set the error document to be index.html?

Comment: @SebastiánRojas or for future references - in the `Static website hosting` config modal you can set the error page, just assign the same value as index page

Comment: @David Finley, can you explain why adding a route to the url causes a 404 in the first place? For example, navigating to 
    ****.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com
works and clicking my dashboard link works fine
    ****.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dashboard
However, if I navigate directly to the url with the dashboard route, I get a 404. I updated my error doc to route to index.html, and that fixed the issue. Thoughts?

Comment: Set the error document to be your index.html fixed my issue.

Answer (score 26):

In my case, I had to specify `index.html` in both `Index document` and `Error document` on S3 Static website hosting properties.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was struggling for 2 hours.

Comment: Yeah, this was a life saver...cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Specifiying index.html in the error page solved the issue for me too.